# accessing the minikube pods externally apart from local machine

Tags: linux, microservices, minikube

I started the minikube process with docker driver, but I am accessing the data on my local machine only. I want to provide that url to client.
can any one help me regarding this issue. is it possible to access the minikube service externally on other machines apart from the local machine ?
my service file is as follows:

```
{
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: xxxx
spec:
  selector:
    app: xxxx
  ports:
    - port: 8080
      targetPort: xxxx
  type: LoadBalancer
}
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

**Important:** minikube is not meant to be used in production. It's mainly an educational tool, used to teach user how kubernetes work in safe, controlled (and usually local) environment. Please, do not use it in production environments.

**Important #2:** Under any circumstances *do not* give access to your local machine to anyone - unless it's a server meant to be accessible from outside organization, and correctly hardened - be it your client or your friend. This is a huge security risk.

Now, off to the question:
Running:

```
minikube service --url <service name>
```

will give you an url with external IP, probably something in `192.168.0.0/16` range (if you are on local network). Then you need to create port forwarding rule on your router.

You can find more details [here](https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/handbook/accessing/).